# Cannot access service on overlay network by IP of manager node(Swarm)

Tags: docker, overlay, docker-swarm

I have setup of 3 swarm nodes. One manager and 2 workers.
I have created service using this command
sudo docker service create --name drupal_new --network my_overlay -p 81:80 drupal

As result service started on one of worker nodes.
ID             NAME              MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE             PORTS
gsosn4xgv4fk   drupal_new        replicated   1/1        drupal:latest     *:81->80/tcp

ID             NAME           IMAGE           NODE           DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE          ERROR     PORTS
qt7y5xj4or3k   drupal_new.1   drupal:latest   docker_test3   Running         Running 24 hours ago

I can access drupal service by IP addresses of worker nodes but I cannot access from IP address of manager node. Can anyone advice what can be reason?

Scheme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### case 1

Check the open ports of your management node ,"nodes" include the management node.

> The following ports must be available. On some systems, these ports are open by default.

```
TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic
```

If the port is not open, please reinitialize swarm cluster after it is open

### case 2

`ip a` to check if there are [docker_gwbridge] on the management node.

If this network is not available, there are two solutions at this point

1. Have you set [ Placement constraints ] ？Set the management node as the eligible node, then the network should be created automatically
2. Or you can create [docker_gwbridge] manually